# Chrome: Freezes for 2 seconds on websites when being loaded

Tags: performance, google-chrome, web, networking, server

I have a weird problem: Two of my little project pages have a "freeze" when being loaded. Independently from each other, when the page ist fetched or loaded for the first time.

Here's a video: https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ah0uXS0-ZrK9kqJ2RoTmBc9lTkHa6g

I tried even with a fresh and clean installation of Chrome. Same problems do occur.

The address of one page is: https://replaying.de if you are curious.

Debug log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/siFXN.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Chrome and will be fixed in the upcoming release! I reported it to them.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. It always freezes on new page load. If I use Ajax calls, then everything seems fine. Here are my results of the log: [F12 Network Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzIa8.jpg)

For what I tested it happens after the DOM is ready, even after the jQuery.ready() statement is being called. So far I was not being able to track exactly what caused the freezing moments.